# webviewのキャッシュ読み込み時に、キャッシュの有無を判定したい。

Tags: android, webview

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
```

というかたちでキャッシュを行っている時に、ページ遷移時にキャッシュが存在したかどうかを判定したいです。

Answer (score 1):

検証してませんがご参考になれば：

webviewが作るキャッシュデータベース(/data/data//databases/webviewCache.db)はsqlite形式です。ページを遷移する前にデータベースをチェックし、当該URLが登録されていなければ、キャッシュには存在しなかったと言えるでしょう。